# Google Cloud BigQuery authentication TransportError 404

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

GCP novice here. I have a simple SQL query to stack overflow dataset:

SQL query code:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
    CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
  view_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
ORDER BY view_count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This runs fine in the Bigquery Web UI so I assume anything relative to project setup, Bigiquery enabling etc is sorted, but when I try this Python code in Compute engine:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

sql = '''
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
    CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
  view_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
ORDER BY view_count DESC
LIMIT 10
'''

query_job = client.query(sql)
df = query_job.to_dataframe()
```

I get a 404 error that is not very explicit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 96, in refresh
    self._retrieve_info(request)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 77, in _retrieve_info
    request, service_account=self._service_account_email
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 219, in get_service_account_info
    recursive=True,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 172, in get
    response,
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ('Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb\'<!DOCTYPE html>\\n<html lang=en>\\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\\n  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\\n  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>\\n  <style>\\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\\n  </style>\\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\\n  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That\\xe2\\x80\\x99s an error.</ins>\\n  <p>The requested URL <code>/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That\\xe2\\x80\\x99s all we know.</ins>\\n\'', <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7fa2026a3710>)
```

Am I missing any bit to enable authentication from within Compute Engine? From the documentation it seems that there's no authentication step required when running from within Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [official documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html) there are four steps in order to use `google-cloud-bigquery` library. One of them is `Setup Authentication`. Additionally, please make sure that your Python version is higher or equal to 3.5.

A common problem with default credentials when running on Google Compute Engine is that the VM does not have sufficient scopes to query BigQuery. So I recommend to authenticate with a Service Account.

You can also refer to [BigQuery Client page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) which shows how to get started with the Cloud Client Libraries for the BigQuery API.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.